# Am unable to login to Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-emulator

I am unable to login to my app with firebase query by using the emulator. The same app is working fine with a mobile device, but when i tried to run it in emulator, the thing is not working. Its rather showing me this error in the logcat:

> 2022-03-15 13:57:44.395 2015-3387/? E/InputDispatcher: Window handle Window{5558fdf u0 com.elijah.ukeme.ecommerceapp/sellers.SellerLoginActivity} has no registered input channel
>
> 2022-03-15 13:58:47.864 2015-3387/? E/InputDispatcher: Window handle Window{abf643 u0 com.elijah.ukeme.ecommerceapp/sellers.SellerLoginActivity} has no registered input channel

Please I need help on how to resolve this, because the same app is working fine in my Android phone but giving me this issues in the emulator. I really need to run it in emulator also, because there's an error that i need to resolve by using the emulator.

Comment: Can you try turning on developer options on the emulator?

Comment: Developer options is enabled in the emulator because the app is being launched successfully and if I launch other apps that doesn't require internet, it is working fine on the emulator, I have the issue only when I am making a network request to the server in which i think that the emulator is not connected to the internet and it normally shows me that error that i posted after a while though the app will still be launched so I don't really know what is the issue @NisaEfendioglu

Comment: I have solved the issue, I deleted the emulator and installed a new one and the issue got resolved. thanks for all your time

Comment: Glad to hear that, good luck! :) @UkemeElijah